# Why can't I replace \n in a given String?

Tags: java, android, string

I found the question here before but somehow I can't see what I'm doing wrong. So I have a given String that looks something like this:

"Some text here\n\nsome more text here"

And I want to remove the linebreaks and display the Text in a TextView. I tried using String.replaceAll:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\n", " ");
```

But that didn't change anything in the text. However, 
`oldString.contains("\\n");` returns **true**. What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

I'm sorry, I know, `oldString` doesn't change. The problem is that, if I print `oldString` and `newString` they're exactly the same even though it says that `oldString` does contain a "\n".

This is my code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "contains: " + str.contains("\\n"));     
Log.d(TAG, "old: " + str);
str = str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");
Log.d(TAG, "new: " + str);
```

And this is what I get:

```
contains: true
old: Vorgang nicht möglich\n\nBitte Karte entnehmen
new: Vorgang nicht möglich\n\nBitte Karte entnehmen
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **Shivanshu Verma**, I tried `str.replace("\\n"" ");` instead of `str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");` and that works! Does anybody know, why I can't use `replaceAll()` here?

Comment: `oldString` didnt change

Comment: If you want `oldstring` to change, then use `oldString = oldString.replaceAll("\\n", " ");` Or simply set `oldString = newString;` after setting `newString`

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: The `\n` characters wont be visible - are you sure that these are newline characters?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an explanation of why replaceAll() didn't work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strings in Java are immutable and as such the new string with the replacements is stored in newString, not oldString.

**EDIT**

I see now that your issue was not actually related to Java String immutability but rather the difference between replace() and replaceAll(). The difference between these is that replaceAll() takes in a *regex* as the first argument, which will then replace any matches with the second argument, whereas replace() simply takes in a CharSequence (of which String is an implementation) and will replace exact matches with the second argument.

In your case, I think your original String had the newline characters escaped:

```
String str = "Vorgang nicht möglich\\n\\nBitte Karte entnehmen";
```

which meant that the String didn't actually contain newline characters at all; it contained literally `"\n"`. This would mean that:

```
str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");
```

will resolve the first argument to a regex and replace newline characters (of which there were none), and:

```
str.replace("\\n", " ");
```

will replace exact matches of `"\n"`. It's also worth noting that as others have pointed out contains() also doesn't take in a regex, which is why running:

```
oldString.contains("\\n");
```

returned true.

Comment: It really does! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine.

This test will pass without any error:

```
@Test
public void testReplaceAll() {


    String newString = "line1\nline2\nline3".replaceAll("\\n", " ");

    assertThat(newString).isEqualTo("line1 line2 line3");
    assertThat(newString).doesNotContain("\\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to Replace() method instead of ReplaceAll()

```
String newString = oldString.replace("\\n", " ");
```

may be it work for u

Comment: That did it! Thanks :) But why doesn't `replaceAll` work  here?

Comment: replaceAll() does not replace the characters in the current string, but returns a string with the characters replaced.

Comment: Also note, strings are immutable in Java. You can NEVER change a string in place

Comment: but shouldn't `str = str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");` work then?

Comment: str = str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");   doesn't work because  u store the new string in same string. which doesnt alllow for replaceAll()

Comment: newstring = str.replaceAll("\\n", " ");
 it work for replaceAl

Answer (score 1):

String newString = oldString.replace("\n", " ");